# How can I create external hive table with PARQUET FORMATE

Tags: azure, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

I am facing a issue on creating hive table on top of parquet file .can someone help on this. I have read many articles but not able to load the parquet file.

I followed this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/external-data/hive-tables)

Comment: Edit your question and add more information - what error do you get, what is your query, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/external-data/hive-tables) , I reproduce same in my environment and got the below results:

If you are creating parquet format, make sure to add **`ROW FORMAT SERDE`**`'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe'`

**Please follow this code for creating external hive table with Parquet format.**

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `demo_table`(
  `first_name` string,
  `Last_name` int)
ROW FORMAT SERDE
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe'
  
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.SymlinkTextInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  'dbfs:/FileStore/'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'totalSize'='2335',
  'numRows'='240',
  'rawDataSize'='2095',
  'COLUMN_STATS_ACCURATE'='true',
  'numFiles'='1',
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1418173653')
```

[image]

**Output:**

[image]